# Ротация на Javascript через определенное время

Tags: javascript

Как осуществить ротацию на Javascript через определенное время (подскажите скрипты или учебные материалы)?
Нужна ротация данных, причем данные могут быть как изображениями, так и текстами, так и изображениями с ссылками и т.д. Т.е. любые типы данных.

Comment: расшифруйте своё понятие ротация, ибо без контекста - это всё что угодно))

    flag = true;
    while(1){
      sleep(1);
      flag = !flag;
    }

Comment: ротация - показ определенных данных через определенный промежуток времени или после определенного действия. В моем случае - через определенный промежуток времени.

Comment: @nick777 в [этой теме][1] я выкладывал скрипт который тебя интересует! Сразу скажу что нужно понять его логику и доработать под себя!


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/50269/ежесекундное-появление-изображений@nick777 в [этой теме][1] я выкладывал скрипт который тебя интересует! Сразу скажу что нужно понять его логику и доработать под себя!


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/50269/ежесекундное-появление-изображений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Образец.

```
<p>Это числа: <span id="numbers"></span>.</p>
```

и

```
var numbers = ["один", "два", "три"];

function rotateNumber() {
    var counter = $("#numbers").data("numbers") || 0;
    $("#numbers").data("numbers", counter == numbers.length - 1 ? 0 : counter + 1).text(numbers[counter]).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateNumber);
}
$(rotateNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть плагин Slider Kit к jquery, выберите вариант на kyrielles.net/sliderkit